# How can I invoke a macro with all points in a catersian product of argument sets?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, metaprogramming

Suppose I have a macro

```
FOO(a, b)
```

and I want to invoke this macro with a certain (fixed) set of possible values for `a`; and a certain fixed set of values for `b`. Thus, if my set of b values is `bar` and `baz` and my set of b values is `fiz` and `bang`, I want:

```
FOO(bar, fiz)
FOO(bar, bang)
FOO(baz, fiz)
FOO(baz, bang)
```

separated either by new lines or by semicolons, or both - that's a minor issue so let's ignore it; the exact order of the 4 invocations is also not important.

Now, if I only had one 'dimension' of parameters, I could use William Swanson's [mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13459454/1593077) (as described here on the site; and there's even a [github repository](https://github.com/swansontec/map-macro) for it), and write

```
MAP(SINGLE_PARAMETER_MACRO, bar, baz, quux)
```

to obtain

```
SINGLE_PARAMETER_MACRO(bar)
SINGLE_PARAMETER_MACRO(baz)
SINGLE_PARAMETER_MACRO(quux)
```

but the thing is, I have *two* dimensions; and it seems to be impossible/tricky to separate your `__VA_ARGS__` into two different sets and iterate the two-dimensional space of pairs of elements from these sets.

Can this be (reasonably) done?

**Notes:**

- I'm interested in a C-preprocessor-based solution, but if you have something that only works in C++ for some strange reason, that's ok too.
- Solution must be compile-time only, and valid mostly everywhere in your C/C++ translation unit; specifically, within class definitions and at file scope.
- You might be guessing this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and you're right; but please don't pick at my motivation since both X and Y are interesting IMHO.
- If you can maintain a lexicographic order of the macro invocations, that would be nice.

Comment: I don't think there are any looping mechanisms in the preprocessor. Why can't you do this in a runtime loop?

Comment: @Barmar: `FOO` may be a declaration or a definition, not a statement. The preprocessor admits a list-head-vs-tail looping mechanism - but it's not inherently multi-dimensional.

Comment: @WilliamSwanson : Perhaps as the author of the related answer you might have some advice for me?

Comment: Maybe you'll be interested in invoking cartesian product in case of function parameters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39687907/is-it-possible-to-invoke-a-method-with-all-possible-k-combinations-with-repetit

Comment: @W.F.: While it doesn't answer this question (the "Y") per se, I think I might be able to adapt something like that to solve my "X" problem. But it's a PITA :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boost preprocessor library can perform Cartesian products already on preprocessor lists and sequences.  You don't specify what preprocessor data types you want to input... assuming that A and B are tuples, and that you have variadics, you can do:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each_product.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/to_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/to_seq.hpp>

#define EVAL(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define FOO_SEMI_DELIM(R,SEQ_X) EVAL(FOO BOOST_PP_SEQ_TO_TUPLE(SEQ_X));
#define FOO_CARTESIAN(TUP_A,TUP_B) \
   BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_PRODUCT \
   ( FOO_SEMI_DELIM, \
     (BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_SEQ(TUP_A)) \
     (BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_SEQ(TUP_B)) \
   )

FOO_CARTESIAN((John,Jane),(Smith,Jones,Parker,Peterson))
```

Since `FOO` is in all caps, I'm assuming you want to wind up calling FOO as a macro; `EVAL` here allows you to do this.

You can easily extend this to Cartesian products of higher dimensions.

Comment: That's my answer. A hefty dependency on the Boost preprocessor mechanism, but that's a reasonable price to pay I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

[`BOOST_REPEAT_PP`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/repeat.html) can help you.

For instance, if you have two arrays of numbers, you could do this in c++14:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

constexpr std::array<int, 2> a = {2, 4};
constexpr std::array<int, 3> b = {1, 3, 7};

#define MYNUMBER2(z, n, x) std::cout << a[x] << " " << b[n] << std::endl;
#define MYNUMBER(z, n, x) BOOST_PP_REPEAT(3, MYNUMBER2, n)

int main() {
  BOOST_PP_REPEAT(2, MYNUMBER, 0); // The "0" is actually not used
}
```

Output:

```
2 1
2 3
2 7
4 1
4 3
4 7
```

If you don't want to use `std::array`, you could also follow some approach like the following (does not require c++14):

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#define A_0 "bar"
#define A_1 "baz"
#define A_2 "ban"

#define B_0 "fiz"
#define B_1 "bang"

#define FOO(s1, s2) std::cout << s1 << " " << s2 << std::endl;
#define MYSTRING2(z, n, x) FOO(A_##x, B_##n)
#define MYSTRING(z, n, x) BOOST_PP_REPEAT(2, MYSTRING2, n)

int main() {
  BOOST_PP_REPEAT(3, MYSTRING, 0); // The "0" is actually not used
}
```

Output:

```
bar fiz
bar bang
baz fiz
baz bang
ban fiz
ban bang
```

Comment: Does this work at file scope, i.e. for definitions/declarations?

Comment: @einpoklum yes, it only performs macro substitution so anything should be possible.

Comment: @einpoklum yes, you can easily use it for declarations. [Example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5iEXuuaDdbp1cdaY).

Comment: This has the drawback of not being able to have the two sets of arguments on the same line / in the same macro invocation, but rather having to define an inner macro - one level of recursion for each parameter of `FOO`. But it's already an improvement so +1.