# Create cartesian product expansion of two variadic, non-type template parameter packs

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, cartesian-product

Lets say, I have

- two lists of non-type template parameteres (which might have a different type)
- a template `foo` that takes one value of each of those lists as a parameter

**How can I create a variadic parameter pack of `foo`s, parameterized with the cartesian product of the two list elements?**

Here is what I mean:

```
template<int ...>
struct u_list {};

template<char ...>
struct c_list {};

template<int, char >
struct foo {};

template<class ...>
struct bar {};

using int_vals = u_list<1, 5, 7>;
using char_vals = c_list<-3, 3>;


using result_t = /* magic happens*/
using ref_t = bar<
    foo<1, -3>, foo<1, 3>,
    foo<5, -3>, foo<5, 3>,
    foo<7, -3>, foo<7, 3>
>;

static_assert(std::is_same<result_t, ref_t >::value, "");
```

I'm looking for a solution that works in c++11 and doesn't use any libraries except the c++11 standard library. I also have my handroled version of c++14's `index_sequence` / `make_index_sequence` and can provide the non-type parameter lists as arrays if that simplifies the code.

The closest I've found so far is this: [How to create the Cartesian product of a type list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122028/how-to-create-the-cartesian-product-of-a-type-list/12521547). So in principle (I haven't tested it) it should be possible to turn the non-type parameter packs into type parameter packs and then apply the solution in the linked post, but I was hoping that there is a simpler / shorter solution along the lines of this:

```
template<int... Ints, char ... Chars>
auto magic(u_list<Ints...>, c_list<Chars...>) 
{
    //Doesn't work, as it tries to expand the parameter packs in lock step
    return bar<foo<Ints,Chars>...>{};  
}

using result_t = decltype(magic(int_vals{}, char_vals{}));
```

Comment: I've been doing some nasty stuff with parameters combinations... maybe this can be helpful: [\[click me\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39687907/is-it-possible-to-invoke-a-method-with-all-possible-k-combinations-with-repetit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may do something like the following:

```
template <int... Is>
using u_list = std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>;

template <char... Cs>
using c_list = std::integer_sequence<char, Cs...>;

template<int, char> struct foo {};

template<class ...> struct bar {};

template <std::size_t I, typename T, template <typename, T...> class C, T ... Is>
constexpr T get(C<T, Is...> c)
{
    constexpr T values[] = {Is...};
    return values[I];
}


template <std::size_t I, typename T>
constexpr auto get_v = get<I>(T{});


template<int... Ints, char ... Chars, std::size_t ... Is>
auto cartesian_product(u_list<Ints...>, c_list<Chars...>, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
-> bar<foo<
        get_v<Is / sizeof...(Chars), u_list<Ints...> >,
        get_v<Is % sizeof...(Chars), c_list<Chars...> >
        >...
    >;

template<int... Ints, char ... Chars>
auto cartesian_product(u_list<Ints...> u, c_list<Chars...> c)
-> decltype(cartesian_product(u, c, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ints) * sizeof...(Chars)>()));




using int_vals = u_list<1, 5, 7>;
using char_vals = c_list<-3, 3>;

using result_t = decltype(cartesian_product(int_vals{}, char_vals{}));
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/300058b6a524fd63)

Possible implementation of std part:

```
template <typename T, T ... Is> struct integer_sequence{};

template <std::size_t ... Is>
using index_sequence = integer_sequence<std::size_t, Is...>;

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct make_index_sequence : make_index_sequence<N - 1, N - 1, Is...> {};

template <std::size_t... Is>
struct make_index_sequence<0u, Is...> : index_sequence<Is...> {};
```

And change in answer:

```
template <std::size_t I, typename T, template <typename, T...> class C, T ... Is>
constexpr T get(C<T, Is...> c)
{
    using array = T[];
    return array{Is...}[I];
}

template<int... Ints, char ... Chars, std::size_t ... Is>
auto cartesian_product(u_list<Ints...>, c_list<Chars...>, index_sequence<Is...>)
-> bar<foo<
        get<Is / sizeof...(Chars)>(u_list<Ints...>{}),
        get<Is % sizeof...(Chars)>(c_list<Chars...>{})
        >...
    >;
```

[Demo C++11](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bc701ab22af23e8)

Comment: Thank you. At a glance, this seems the solution, that is most readable to me. I'll have to experiment a bit with the real code to see what answer works best for me.

Comment: Could you translate this into a c++11 solution?

Comment: @MikeMB: C++11 version added.

Answer (score 2):

Doing template metaprogramming in the domain of pure types is far easier in my opinion.

It takes some work to move from the land of non-type template parameters to the land of types and back again, but it means you are using generic metaprogramming utilities instead of ones specific to your problem.

---

So I'll reduce your problem to a cartesian product on a list of types.

Here is my type pack:

```
template<class...Ts>struct types {
  using type=types; // makes inheriting from it useful
  static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(Ts);
};
```

First we write `fmap`.  Fmap takes a function and a list, and returns a list of each element of the list with the function applied.

```
template<template<class...>class Z, class List>
struct fmap {};
template<template<class...>class Z, class List>
using fmap_t = typename fmap<Z,List>::type;
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
struct fmap<Z, types<Ts...>>:
  types<Z<Ts>...>
{};
```

and `fapply`.  fapply takes a function and a list as well, but applies the function to the entire set of list elements.

```
template<template<class...>class Z, class List>
struct fapply {};
template<template<class...>class Z, class List>
using fapply_t=typename fapply<Z,List>::type;
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
struct fapply<Z, types<Ts...>> {
  using type=Z<Ts...>;
};
```

As it happens, partial application of `fapply` is very useful:

```
template<template<class...>class Z>
struct applier {
    template<class List>
    using apply = fapply_t<Z,List>;
};
```

We'll want to be able to concatinate lists:

```
template<class...>
struct cat:types<> {};
template<class...As, class...Bs, class...Cs>
struct cat<types<As...>, types<Bs...>, Cs...>:
    cat<types<As..., Bs...>, Cs...>
{};
template<class...As>
struct cat<types<As...>>:types<As...>{};
template<class...Ts>using cat_t=typename cat<Ts...>::type;
```

Then, here is cart_product_t:

```
template<class A, class B>
struct cart_product {};
template<class A, class B>
using cart_product_t = typename cart_product<A,B>::type;
template<class A, class... Bs>
struct cart_product<types<A>, types<Bs...>>:
  types< types<A, Bs>... >
{};
// reduce cart_product to cart_product on a one element list on the lhs:
template<class...As, class... Bs>
struct cart_product<types<As...>, types<Bs...>>:
  fapply_t<
    cat_t,
    fmap_t<
      applier<cart_product_t>::template apply,
      types<
        types< types<As>, types<Bs...> >...
      >
    >
  >
{};
```

Types specific to your problem:

```
template<int...>struct u_list {};
template<char...>struct c_list {};
template<int, char>struct foo {};
template<class...>struct bar{};
```

A tool that lift lists of values to types:

```
template<class> struct lift {};
template<int...is> struct lift<u_list<is...>>:
  types< std::integral_constant<int, is>... >
{};
template<char...is> struct lift<c_list<is...>>:
  types< std::integral_constant<char, is>... >
{};
template<class T>using lift_t=typename lift<T>::type;
```

lower_to_foo takes a pair of types, and converts them to a foo:

```
template<class I, class C>
using lower_to_foo = foo<I::value, C::value>;
```

now we put them together:

```
using int_vals = u_list<1, 5, 7>;
using char_vals = c_list<-3, 3>;

using product = cart_product_t< lift_t<int_vals>, lift_t<char_vals> >;
static_assert( product::size == 6, "should be 6" );
using result_t = fapply_t< bar, fmap_t< applier<lower_to_foo>::template apply, product > >;

using ref_t = bar<
  foo<1, -3>, foo<1, 3>,
  foo<5, -3>, foo<5, 3>,
  foo<7, -3>, foo<7, 3>
>;
ref_t test = result_t{}; // gives better error messages than static_assert
static_assert(std::is_same<result_t, ref_t >::value, "");
```

and bob is your uncle.

`cat`, `fmap` and `fapply` are both relatively standard functions in functional programming.  `applier` just lets you write your template mapping functions taking elements instead of lists (it is a partially applied `fapply`).

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/371521a6c1c018e4).

---

Now, remember how I said template metaprogramming was easier with types?

Notice all those template template parameters?  It gets easier if they are types.

```
template<template<class...>class Z>
struct ztemplate {
  template<class...Ts>using apply=Z<Ts...>;
};
```

and you can go all the way down to hana-style constexpr metaprogramming with type tags and `operator()` on `ztemplate` and other fun.

Comment: Does std::integral_constant actually have to have a integral type or are e.g. class enums also possible?

Comment: @MikeMB Mate, function pointers are even possible.  They even are callable in C++14.

Comment: Thank you. This seems like a good solution, but unless we need more tmp in our code, I'm a bit reluctant to add so many generic facilities just for my single usecase.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the type-list cross product as a base

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cxxabi.h>

template<int ...> struct u_list {};

template<char ...> struct c_list {};

template<int, char > struct foo {};

template<typename...> struct type_list {};
```

We expand the `char...` pack with `row`

```
template<int I, char... Cs>
  struct row
{
  typedef type_list<foo<I,Cs>...> type;
};

template <typename... T> struct concat;

template <typename... S, typename... T>
struct concat<type_list<S...>, type_list<T...>>
{
    using type = type_list<S..., T...>;
};
```

We want an extra specialisation of `concat` to break out of the base case

```
template <typename... T>
struct concat<type_list<T...>, void>
{
    using type = type_list<T...>;
};

template<typename I, typename C>
struct cross_product;
```

Base case: no more ints

```
template<char... Cs>
struct cross_product<u_list<>, c_list<Cs...>>
{
    using type = void;
};
```

Recursive case: An int, followed by a pack of ints

```
template<int I, int... Is, char... Cs>
struct cross_product<u_list<I, Is...>, c_list<Cs...>>
{
    using type = typename concat<typename row<I,Cs...>::type, typename cross_product<u_list<Is...>, c_list<Cs...>>::type>::type;

};

int main()
{
  using int_vals = u_list<1, 5, 7>;
  using char_vals = c_list<-3, 3>;

  using result_t = cross_product<int_vals, char_vals>::type;
  using ref_t = type_list<
      foo<1, -3>, foo<1, 3>,
      foo<5, -3>, foo<5, 3>,
      foo<7, -3>, foo<7, 3>
  >;

  static_assert(std::is_same<result_t, ref_t >::value, "");
  return 0;
}
```

[Live on Coliru!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38bafd12f4b8dec0)

Answer (score 0):

The following are my 2 cents...

If you want a generic solution, the bigger problem I see is that from `int_vals` and `char_vals` types isn't easy (in C++11; simpler in C++17) extract the types of the contained values (`int` and `char`).

So I suppose you have to pass they to `magic<>` together with `foo` and `bar` (if you don't want `foo` and `bar` hard-coded).

So the call to `magic<>` become (in my way)

```
using result_t
   = typename magic<int, char, foo, bar, int_vals, char_vals>::type;
```

The following is a full working example with my solution.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <int...>  struct u_list {};
template <char...> struct c_list {};

template <int, char>    struct foo {};
template <typename ...> struct bar {};

template <typename T1, typename T2, T1 t1, T2 ... T2s>
struct midProd
 { };

template <typename T1, typename T2, template <T1, T2> class, typename...>
struct magicHelper;

template <typename T1, typename T2,
          template <T1, T2> class ResIn,
          template <typename...> class ResOut,
          typename ... R>
struct magicHelper<T1, T2, ResIn, ResOut<R...>>
 { using type = ResOut<R...>; };

template <typename T1, typename T2,
          template <T1, T2> class ResIn,
          template <typename...> class ResOut,
          typename ... R, T1 ts1, T2 ... ts2, typename ... MpS>
struct magicHelper<T1, T2, ResIn, ResOut<R...>,
              midProd<T1, T2, ts1, ts2...>, MpS...>
 { using type = typename magicHelper<T1, T2, ResIn,
                   ResOut<R..., ResIn<ts1, ts2>...>, MpS...>::type; };


template <typename T1, typename T2,
          template <T1, T2> class,
          template <typename...> class,
          typename, typename>
struct magic;

template <typename T1, typename T2,
          template <T1, T2> class ResIn,
          template <typename...> class ResOut,
          template <T1...> class C1, template <T2...> class C2,
          T1 ... ts1, T2 ... ts2>
struct magic<T1, T2, ResIn, ResOut, C1<ts1...>, C2<ts2...>>
 { using type = typename magicHelper<T1, T2, ResIn, ResOut<>,
                   midProd<T1, T2, ts1, ts2...>...>::type ; };

int main ()
 {
   using int_vals  = u_list<1, 5, 7>;
   using char_vals = c_list<-3, 3>;

   using result_t
      = typename magic<int, char, foo, bar, int_vals, char_vals>::type;

   using ref_t = bar< foo<1, -3>, foo<1, 3>,
                      foo<5, -3>, foo<5, 3>,
                      foo<7, -3>, foo<7, 3> >;

   static_assert(std::is_same<result_t, ref_t >::value, "");
 }
```

Obviously, if you prefer hard-code some types (`u_list`, `c_list`, `foo`, and `bar`), the solution become a lot simpler

```
#include <type_traits>

template <int...>  struct u_list {};
template <char...> struct c_list {};

template <int, char>    struct foo {};
template <typename ...> struct bar {};

template <int, char...> struct midProd {};

template <typename...>
struct magicH;

template <typename ... R>
struct magicH<bar<R...>>
 { using type = bar<R...>; };

template <typename ... R, int i, char ... cs, typename ... MpS>
struct magicH<bar<R...>, midProd<i, cs...>, MpS...>
 { using type = typename magicH<bar<R..., foo<i, cs>...>, MpS...>::type; };


template <typename, typename>
struct magic;

template <int ... is, char ... cs>
struct magic<u_list<is...>, c_list<cs...>>
 { using type = typename magicH<bar<>, midProd<is, cs...>...>::type; };

int main ()
 {
   using int_vals  = u_list<1, 5, 7>;
   using char_vals = c_list<-3, 3>;

   using result_t = typename magic<int_vals, char_vals>::type;

   using ref_t = bar< foo<1, -3>, foo<1, 3>,
                      foo<5, -3>, foo<5, 3>,
                      foo<7, -3>, foo<7, 3> >;

   static_assert(std::is_same<result_t, ref_t >::value, "");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The same as others in C++17:

```
// Type your code here, or load an example.
#include <type_traits>

template<int ...>
struct u_list {};

template<char ...>
struct c_list {};

template<int, char >
struct foo {};

template<class ...>
struct bar {};

using int_vals = u_list<1, 5, 7>;
using char_vals = c_list<-3, 3>;

template<class... Args> struct type_list{
    template<class> struct make_concat;
    template<class ...Xs>
    struct make_concat<type_list<Xs...>>{
        using type = type_list<Args...,Xs...>;
    };
    template<class T>
    using concat = typename make_concat<T>::type;
    template<template<class...>class TT>
    using applied_to = TT<Args...>;
};

template<
         template<auto,auto> class C
        ,class X,class Y,class Yit=Y>
struct cart_prod;
template<template<auto,auto> class C,
         template<auto...> class Xt,
         template<auto...> class Yt,
         class Yit,
         auto Xi,auto...Xis,auto Yi,auto...Yis>
struct cart_prod<C,Xt<Xi,Xis...>,Yt<Yi,Yis...>,Yit>{
    using type = typename type_list<class C<Xi,Yi>>
       ::template concat<typename cart_prod<C,Xt<Xi,Xis...>,Yt<Yis...>,Yit>::type>;
};
template<template<auto,auto> class C,
         template<auto...> class Xt,
         template<auto...> class Yt,
         class Yit,
         auto Xi,auto...Xis,auto Yi>
struct cart_prod<C,Xt<Xi,Xis...>,Yt<Yi>,Yit>{
    using type = typename type_list<class C<Xi,Yi>>
       ::template concat<typename cart_prod<C,Xt<Xis...>,Yit,Yit>::type>;
};
template<template<auto,auto> class C,
         template<auto...> class Xt,
         template<auto...> class Yt,
         class Yit,
         auto Xi,auto Yi>
struct cart_prod<C,Xt<Xi>,Yt<Yi>,Yit>{
    using type = type_list<class C<Xi,Yi>>;
};


using result_t = cart_prod<foo,int_vals,char_vals>::type::applied_to<bar>;
using ref_t = bar<
    foo<1, -3>, foo<1, 3>,
    foo<5, -3>, foo<5, 3>,
    foo<7, -3>, foo<7, 3>
>;

static_assert(std::is_same<result_t, ref_t >::value, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

yet another (but shorter) solution might be

```
template<typename Ret,typename R>
auto magic( bar<u_list<>, R>, Ret result, R ) { return result; }

template<int I, int... Ints, typename... Foos, typename R>
auto magic( bar<u_list<I,Ints...>, c_list<>>, bar<Foos...>, R rollback ) { return magic(
    bar<u_list<Ints...>,R>{}, bar<Foos...>{}, rollback );}

template<int I, int... Ints, char J, char ... Chars, typename... Foos, typename R >
auto magic( bar<u_list<I,Ints...>, c_list<J,Chars...>>, bar<Foos...>, R rollback ) { return magic(
    bar<u_list<I,Ints...>, c_list<Chars...>>{},
    bar<Foos...,foo<I,J>>{},
    rollback );}

using result_t = decltype(magic( bar<int_vals,char_vals>{}, bar<>{}, char_vals{} ));
```